# Moving forward in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

```
    var leftKey = 72;

    var rightKey = 74;


    document.onkeydown = checkKey;
    function checkKey(e){
        e = e || window.event;
    if(e.keyCode === leftKey){
           car.position.z = car.position.z -10;

       }
    if(e.keyCode === rightKey){
           car.position.z = car.position.z +10;

       }
    } 

    car.position.x ++;
```

Hello, I am trying to move car forward every update of the game. But the code 'car.position.x +++;' throws the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined'. How can I fix this? Thank you!

```
myColladaLoader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
myColladaLoader.options.convertUpAxis = true;

myColladaLoader.load( 'car.DAE', function ( collada ) {
        // Her the dae in a global variable.
        car = collada.scene;

        // Position your model in the scene (world space).
        car.position.x = -1850;
        car.position.y = 0;
        car.position.z = 0;

        // Scale your model to the correct size.
        car.scale.x = car.scale.y = car.scale.z = 0.2;
        car.updateMatrix();

        // Add the model to the scene.
        scene.add( car );
    } );
```

Adding car above!

Comment: Include the code where `car` is defined.

Comment: Its brought in from a .dae file

Comment: Apparently it's `undefined` on the line where you try to increate it's `x` property.

Comment: car.position.x = -1850; this is where i create the property, let me edit the question showing the creation of the car two secs

Comment: The problem is that `car` is undefined so therefore it has no `position` property. Where did you define the `car` variable? From the looks it seems that you have scoping issues.

Comment: But i am able to move the car using the keyboard? How can I fix this issue

Comment: @PavlosNicolaou As I edited on my comment, where do you define `var car`? To me it seems to be a scoping issue and the fact that you're declaring the `car` variable in another scope so it can't be read from your other piece of code. The `car` variable still works in *its own scope* which is why you can control it.

Comment: Its a global variable, I am able to move the car on the x axis if i use the keyboard, but not if I try to move it automatically

Comment: @PavlosNicolaou But it's obviously not a global variable when you can't access car in your other scope (unless its value is `undefined`). Have you tried to `console.log(car)` and `console.log(window)` to see your *actual* global variables?

Comment: I dont understand your issues with scope? I'm a novice to using three.js so bare with me. I would of thought, if I'm able to control the car from render(), why aren't I able to move the car forward using render()?

Comment: Just because the car exists and works in its own scope doesn't mean that you can access it. Consider this: Just because I'm doing something in my own house doesn't automatically mean that you can enter the house and talk to me. We're both living human beings that can do stuff, but that doesn't mean we can interact. In the same way, if `car` is defined in a different scope (think "house") then you need to have access to the scope (think "outside the house") or use a global scope (think "park"). [*What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?*](http://goo.gl/lXWLHe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here obviously is not scoping error but javascript render function is updating before car is even implemented.
The way to fix this is to delay the car of going forward until is there.

Please have a look at [three.js Documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/)